# Why video is started from last end position?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, youtube-api

I have a problem with `youtube-api` when i load a video. I am using `loadVideoById` function. I have tried also `cueVideoById` but the result is the same.

OK, here is what it is about.
when i play some video at **YouTube** page and will finish it in for `example` middle. YouTube will remember that position and next time i enter this video it will play from that position. Also im logged in in the `Chrome` browser. So when i load this video at my page using `youtube api` by function mentioned before it also starts this video from previously remembered position.

I tried to use `stopVideo` or `seekTo(0)` after loading it but it doesnt work. Also when i change the time of video and press stop and play next it will start again from remember position. Does anyone know the solution for this ?

JS fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/or2w8fpd/6/

Just open video by youtube side stop in the middle, check if youtube saved your position for future (if you return to video where does progress start) then open jsfiddle and try it. remember to be logged in to chrome browser

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example on jsfiddle?